# Predict game time event to IRL time

Tags: javascript, datetime, math

In the game " 7 days to die ", there is a event (blood moon) every sunday at 22pm.
My server settings are 90 minutes IRL per in-game day.
I want to create a discord bot with discord.JS that display a prediction of the starting event with IRL date time.

I have an API endpoint that return the current gametime :

```
{"gametime":{"days":527,"hours":17,"minutes":29}}
```

What i've tried :

```js
  const IN_GAME_DAY_MINUTES = 90

  let nextBloodInGameDays = ( 7 - ( gametime.days % 7 ) ) + 1
  if (nextBloodInGameDays == 8) {
    // Do this to ensure sunday is 1 to have 90 remainingRealRawMinutes 
    nextBloodInGameDays = 1
  }

  let remainingRealRawMinutes = nextBloodInGameDays * IN_GAME_DAY_MINUTES

  let currentDayMinutesLeft = ((24 - gametime.hours) * 60) - gametime.minutes

  let minutesPerGameHour = (IN_GAME_DAY_MINUTES / 24)

  let currentDayRealMinutesLeft = (currentDayMinutesLeft * minutesPerGameHour / 60)
 
  let nextBloodAt = new Date()

  // Add raw time 
  nextBloodAt.setMinutes(nextBloodAt.getMinutes() + remainingRealRawMinutes)
```

But now i'm stuck on how to decrement `currentDayRealMinutesLeft` on `remainingRealRawMinute` to get a fixed time (and the extra 2 ingame hours

I'm learning programming and my english may be wrong, thank you in advance :)

Comment: It looks like nextBloodAt should be a fixed time. What are you expecting to have, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: I expect by substracting `currentDayRealMinutesLeft` on `remainingRealRawMinute` to get a fixed time, but what I tried, the time continue to increase, I can't get a fixed time ( this code run inside a `setInterval` function that query a HTTP endpoint.

I can't share the code I tried because i'm totally wrong after what to do after `nextBloodAt.setMinutes`

Comment: Does the event happen on Sunday at 22:00 in game or in real life?

Comment: yes, the event is in-game

Comment: You need an epoch to align real time with game time, i.e. given `"gametime":{"days":527,"hours":17,"minutes":29}`, what is/was the real time at that moment? Presumably if a game day is 90 minutes then that is about 47,500 real minutes (or about 18 months game–time and about 32.9 days real time).